# Invoke a function from a procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a PL/SQL procedure that will invoke a function I called GET_HIGHORDER_FUNC which is already working:

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_HIGHORDER_FUNC
  return number
AS
  c_hiorder number;
BEGIN 
  select max(sum(product.product_standardprice * orderline.ordered_quantity)) into c_hiorder
    from customer, product, orderline, orders
    where customer.customer_id = orders.customer_id 
    and orders.order_id = orderline.order_id
    and orderline.product_id = product.product_id 
    group by customer_name;
  RETURN c_hiorder;
END GET_HIGHORDER_FUNC;

create or replace procedure PRINT_CUST_PROC(
    p_hiordername in number)
as 

begin
 /* This procedure should show the name of the customer who have the highest
    amount of order which will be available upon invoking the function above */
end;
```

Comment: (Unrelated) 
Tip of today: Use the modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just invoke it as you would with any function?

This is how i would try based on your latest comments

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_HIGHORDER_FUNC(c_customer_name out varchar2,c_hiorder out int)
  return number
AS
  c_hiorder number;
BEGIN 
select y.customer_name
      ,y.summed_price
 into customer_name
     ,c_hiorder 
 from (
         select x.customer_name
               ,x.summed_price
               ,row_number() over(order by x.summed_price desc) as rnk
        from (     
          select customer_name
                 ,sum(product.product_standardprice * orderline.ordered_quantity) as summed_price
            from customer, product, orderline, orders
            where customer.customer_id = orders.customer_id 
            and orders.order_id = orderline.order_id
            and orderline.product_id = product.product_id 
         group by customer_name    
             )x
      )y
where y.rnk=1;

  RETURN 1;
END GET_HIGHORDER_FUNC;

create or replace procedure PRINT_CUST_PROC(
    p_hiordername in number)
as 
l_return int;
l_customer_name varchar2(1000);
l_hiorder int;
begin
 /* This procedure should show the name of the customer who have the highest
    amount of order which will be available upon invoking the function above 
    */
l_return : = GET_HIGHORDER_FUNC(l_customer_name,l_hiorder);
dbms_output.put_line(l_customer_name);
dbms_output.put_line(l_hiorder);
end;
```

Comment: Actually here's the problem I'm dealing with. I'm very new to this things. sorry. Create a procedure that displays the name of the customer with the highest amount of orders among 
all customers. Name the procedure PRINT_CUST_PROC. The procedure will also invoke a function 
called GET_HIGHORDER_FUNC that retrieve
s the name and 
total 
amount
ordered
of 
customer
with the 
highest 
amount of 
order
. Invoke the procedure and view the results.

Comment: I Tested the function and I got the output which I think is corret.

Comment: check and share your feedback

Comment: It worked, just few editing and boom! Awesome. Thank you so much George!